# how to set a float number for min/max value of apex chart axis

Tags: oracle-apex

What I'm trying to do is "to set a value for minimum/maximum of chart axis in apex" but it's not possible to enter a float value. 
just int is allowed. 
what should I do?

Comment: I think one of these can be the answer:
   1. pass the value of variable to minimum or maximum which is defined before, using "{!varname}" 
   2.define (create) a function that passess the value to minimum or maximum
   3.by dynamic action: on click or page load: 
$("#idid").options: {scales: { yAxes: [{ ticks: {min:0.7}....});
   4.force software (by editing related utilities) to show more selectable datatypes in list!!!